# Using uber API to schedule rides for others (customers)

Tags: uber-api

1.
I've been researching into the Uber API and I can't seem to find concrete information regarding whether or not you can request rides for other people. I want to be able to offer clients that come to my business a ride home or a ride to my business. I see Uber Central is meant to fill that, but is there a way to use the API to do what Uber Central is made to do?

2.
 Also, is it possible to use the Uber Central API (if it exists) to charge the customer for the ride?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a directly publicly available API to pay for other's rides currently. As you mention, Uber Central (https://help.uber.com/h/502388e3-df83-4c4b-964d-625a1d161e12) is a good option but does not have a public API available.

Another suggestion that might be useful for you is https://vouchers.uber.com which allows you to buy promo codes for a specific location. Again, this is not available currently in an API.

This is an area that the Uber API team is exploring, however, so keep an eye out for any announcements.

Cheers.